# CentOS 7 escape "-r"

Tags: centos7, command-line-interface

I am using CentOS 7. I have a folder name "-r". This happened accidentally when I executed a tar command. I need to remove this folder but somehow -r option is taken as switch to the commands rm,rename,mv etc.. How do I remove this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove this folder you can try something like:

```
rm -r -- -r
```

Double dash tell to command this is the end of options and follow arguments (in your case directory name)

Comment: Also possible: `rmdir ./-r` (using `rmdir` assuming the directory is empty.) Using `./` to refer to local files is enough to prevent commands from interpreting them as options.